# Disable hardware back button in Ionic application?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, dom-events

I'm trying to disable the back button on my Cordova app.
I'm using AngularJS + Ionic Framework.
I found topics about this and tried the code bellow, but it has absolutely no effect. Any idea?

index.html

```
<head>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("hello");
            }, false );
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Note that when I push back button, I have "hello" displayed in my console.

Comment: Solution for Ionic v2 (also v3): Link http://stackoverflow.com/a/43860391/5125608

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally found the answer on [this](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-the-hardware-back-buttons/1505/7) Ionic Forum thread:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
  if (condition) {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  } else {
    handle back action!
  }
}, 100);
```

`$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` allows to completly overwrite back button behavior. 
First param is a callback function and the secondone a priority (only the callback with the highest priority gets executed).

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Ionic v1.1.0 and a Nexus 6?

Comment: Actually it does work, but only on top level states from 'sectionA' to 'sectionB' but not 'sectionA.subsectionA' to 'sectionA.subsectionB'

Comment: @KimT Yes you are absolutely right. Did you find any solution, how to disable device back button in nested views?

Comment: To fix ionic view animations I used: $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'); and set the correct direction in the view: $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection(direction);

Comment: How can we prevent/disable the back button when a loading is present in Ionic4?

Answer (score 23):

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, 100);
```

this will prevent back button functionality.

Answer (score 14):

To expand upon David D's answer I have included the go back implementation.

Put this in your applications `.run` function:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
  if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'someStateName'){
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  }
}, 100);
```

This will not work in controllers, it is application wide.

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Ionic v1.1.0 and a Nexus 6?

Comment: Actually it does work, but only on top level states from 'sectionA' to 'sectionB' but not 'sectionA.subsectionA' to 'sectionA.subsectionB'

Answer (score 4):

Its simple trick prevent go back to single page:

```
  `.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$ionicHistory) {
                $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                $ionicHistory.clearHistory();

       })`
```

Answer (score 2):

The example in the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) shows the event listeners — even the `deviceready` — being attached after the document `onload` event has fired.

Using your code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello");
  }, false);
}

document.onload = function () {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
};
```

Comment: Still no effect :( I guess it's because I'm using Ionic (which include Cordova).

Answer (score 2):

To prevent App from device back button functionality use,

```
      $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
      }, 100);
```

If you want to prevent the particular page use,

```
       $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           if ($location.path() === "/pagename" || $location.path() === "pagename") {
             navigator.app.exitApp();
           } else {
             $ionicHistory.goBack();
           }
        }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable hardware back button in Ionic application for controller (or controller of component), you can make the following workaround, but first it is actually not for controller itself, but it combination between controllers and state, in your controller, add your normal code:

```
  var deRegisterHardBack = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
      function (event) {
        if (youConditionHere) {
          event.preventDefault();
          // do something
        } else {
          $ionicHistory.goBack();
        }
      }, 100);
```

But in your `$stateProvider` add `disableHardwareBackButton` like the following:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('app.stateB', {
        url: '/page-b/:id',
        template: '<ion-view><ion-nav-title>Sub Page </ion-nav-title>Hello</ion-view>',
        disableHardwareBackButton : true
      });
```

Inside your module('app').run function:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event){
   if ($state.current.disableHardwareBackButton){
      event.preventDefault();
   } else {
      $ionicHistory.goBack();
   }
}
```

In this way you get around the issue with "sub section" or "inside controller"

Answer (score 1):

**For Ionic 3:**

```
// root component
export class MyApp {

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        this.customBackButtonHandler();
      }, 100)
    });
  }

  customBackButtonHandler() {
    ...
  }

}
```