# How to disable back button when use ionic modal on android?

Tags: android, modal-dialog, ionic-framework

I try to disable back button on android device with "keyboard: false" but it not work.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  keyboard: false
})
```

How to disable it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ionicModal provides `hardwareBackButtonClose` option to set `false` for this behaviour.

```
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      hardwareBackButtonClose: false
  })
```

Please see related documentation : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be: isShown() method as mentioned in the docs *http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/*

You can go for something like this
    if(!$scope.modal.isShown()){
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    } else{
      //do nothing...
 }

Answer (score -1):

Check this thread: [Disable hardware back button in Ionic application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548418/disable-hardware-back-button-in-ionic-application)

This should do it:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
  if (condition) {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  } else {
    handle back action!
  }
}, 100);
```

But I would advice against this unless you really need to. Breaking the expected model of operation very slightly hurts the entire platform.